# How to show just the N first number of rows on DataTables? How to download all data after this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to show only the first N rows of data on DataTables, but can't find a way.

Additionally, when I click the Copy or Excel buttons I want to download all the data, and not just the rows who are being show.

In my last try, I used `paging` and `pageLength` without success. Below is the code. My data is on `tbldata`:

```
var dtable = $("#dvTableAC").DataTable({
    data: tbldata,
    columns: [
        { title: "A" },
        { title: "B" },
        { title: "C" },
        { title: "D" }
    ],
    "paging": false,
    "pageLength": 50,
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excel', 'copy'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please not that you need an extra plugin to be able to use the buttons (excel, copy).
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/built-in

```
var dtable = $("#dvTableAC").DataTable({
    data: tbldata,
    columns: [
        { title: "A" },
        { title: "B" },
        { title: "C" },
        { title: "D" }
    ],
    "paging": true,
    "pageLenght":10,
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excel', 'copy'
    ]
});
```

Datatables will show all the data you send to it, if you set paging to false, then pageLenght is not used. If you want to limit the total records that datatables show, you must send just those records to it. You can restrict the number on the mysql query using limit 10. But I don't know any method of not having pagination and show only a x amount of rows from the total.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vidal! In fact, I would like to solve this with 'paging: false' and not 'true'. I edited my question.

Comment: OK you got me confused, you have 100 records and you want to show only 10, what do you want to do with the 90 left ?

Comment: I have almost 50k rows. I just want to show the N first, but I would like to download/copy all.

Comment: That's fine you should look into the ajax in this way you only query and get the ones that you show, on the other hand I don't know how the excel button behaves if it will download only the one's that you are showing or is going to get the full data via ajax.